# Linking accounts

Tags: html

I'm wondering let's say if i signup in a website and they have a "link your account to gmail / hotmail / yahoo mail / facebook" etc.. is it possible that these "links" (yes after I've linked them) could send automatic emails to my contacts without my knowledge?

Comment: First off, if you give the site your password, then they have full access to your email account. Second, this is not a programming question, so off-topic. Voting to close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Honestly, it depends on the permissions you gave.

Most sites (such as Facebook) allow you to link the account, but display a security dialog when doing so. This dialog outlines the necessary permissions this site requires (or desires) and you then have the options to allow or deny these permissions.

At some level of elevations I'm almost certain you can allow the site access to your contact list, which could either be allowed to send messages via the site itself (through your account) or scrape your contacts and send out mailings of their own.

Long story short, don't be quick to hit "allow" if you feel your own level of security is being impeded.